# How to grab filter the numbers of results

Tags: grep

I use `grep -E '^[ 0-9]{6}$'` to grab strings of 5 digits (numbers or space) in files

It returns:

```
71 051
17 293
017299
862610
```

But is it possible to extract only the 2 first occurrences?
If possible like this in this example "71051-17293"?

Comment: Like this? [Can I grep only the first n lines of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762274/can-i-grep-only-the-first-n-lines-of-a-file)

Comment: I suggest to take a look at `awk`.

Comment: Is that what you searched for? Could you accept the solution or edit your question?

Answer (score 2):

Two options to grep only two lines max:

```
$ grep -Em2 '^[ 0-9]{6}$'
71 051
17 293
$ grep -E '^[ 0-9]{6}$' | head -n2
71 051
17 293
```